# Python Source Unicode to ASCII

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I have a problem converting HTML to normal text. I'm reading some pages and those include unicode signs like \u00f3 and \u00f1, etc. I want those converted to normal ASCII (not ó and ñ but o and n).

I've tried a lot in Python, but does anyone know an easy solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Unicode string matching by folding in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410308/how-to-implement-unicode-string-matching-by-folding-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this S-O question : [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Two good library as a solution :

Unicode (may add characters) and unicodedata (troncate)

Comment: Found the solution:

(1) .decode("unicode-escape")
(2) unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', webLine).encode('ascii','ignore')